# Using PyQT, how do you filter mousePressEvent for a QComboBox with custom list

Tags: python, qt, qt4, pyqt, qcombobox

I've got a `QComboBox` with a custom list object.

[image: Screenshot.]

The custom list object has a custom `mousePressEvent` so that when the user click on one of the circles with a +/- (a twisty), the list is expanded/collapsed.

When I use the list with the combo box, when the user clicks on a twisty, the list is expanded/collapsed, but the selection is changed, and the list is hidden. How can I filter this so that when the user click on a twisty, the selection is not changed, and the list not hidden.

### Additional screenshots

All of the nodes collapsed:
[image: All nodes collapsed.]

List hidden:
[image: Screenshot with the list hidden.]

Comment: Can you post another screenshot where the list is hidden? I don't quite follow what is happening when the list is collapsed.

Comment: The original screen shot shows some of the nodes expanded.
This screen shot shows all the nodes collapsed: http://garyvdm.googlepages.com/revision-selector-collapased.png
This screen shot shows the list hidden:
http://garyvdm.googlepages.com/revision-selector-hidden.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QT has a `eventFilter` that "captures" `QEvent.MouseButtonRelease`. So what I have done is installed my own `eventFilter` that filters `QEvent.MouseButtonRelease` events if the user click on a node.

In my list object I have the following method:

```
def mousePressEvent (self, e):
    self.colapse_expand_click = False
    if <user clicked node>:
        colapse_expand_node()
        e.accept ()
        self.colapse_expand_click = True
```

The `mousePressEvent` runs before `mouseReleaseEvent`.

Then in the custom combobox, I filter the event:

```
class RevisionSelectorWidget(QtGui.QComboBox):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QtGui.QComboBox.__init__(self, parent)

        self.log_list = RevisionSelectorLogList(self)
        self.setView(self.log_list)
        self.log_list.installEventFilter(self)
        self.log_list.viewport().installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, object, event):
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonRelease:
            if self.log_list.colapse_expand_click:
                return True
        return False
```

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head, you could subclass `QComboBox` and override `hideEvent(QHideEvent)` (inherited from `QWidget`)

```
def hideEvent(self, event):
  if self.OkToHide():
    event.accept()
  else:
    event.ignore()
```

Your screenshot looks like an interesting use of a combo box, I'm curious as to why you haven't used a `TreeView` style control instead of a list?

**Edit (Mar 14 2009):**

I looked at the Qt source code and it looks like when the keyboard and mouse events are captured, that as soon as qt has decided to emit the `"activated(int index)"` signal, `"hidePopup()"` has been called.

So apart from rewriting their event filter code, another option is to connect the `"activated(int index)"` or `"highlighted(int index)"` signal to a slot that can call `"showPopup()"` which would re-raise the list items. If you get a nasty disappear/appear paint issue you may have to get Qt to delay the paint events while the popup is visible.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Just for perfect clarity, you would have to implement self.OkToHide() obviously :)

Comment: I tried that on the combo box. hideEvent only gets called when the window is close. I added the following hideEvent to the list. It gets called - but does not prevent hiding.

def hideEvent(self, event):
    event.ignore()

Comment: > Why not a TreeView?

Well - I am using a TreeView control - but I've reimplemented the expanding and collapsing of nodes - because the data that I am displaying is a DAG and not a tree - to the requirement are a bit different. 

See for an example of a DAG:
http://garyvdm.googlepages.com/qlog.png

Comment: thanks @NorthCat. Man the long tail on these answers is amazing :D